# Angular 5 blank page when reload a page in production

Tags: angular5

I have a problem, when I deploy to production my project (Angular 5). The navigation between pages works well, but when I reload the page or write the URL directly in the browser, it throws an Error 404, even though the URL does exist. I added `{useHash: true}` in `app-routing.module.ts` and it works correctly, but it also adds (#) as part of the URL.

i.e. `http://myUrl.com/#/login/`

I would like to be able to reload the page or to write the URL directly without using the hash (#)

Comment: which browser are you using? can you show your routing module?

Comment: Sorry but i can't get the routing file, but this problem ocurrs with any browser, any way i was investigating, and find that is more commonly to use apache instead of nginx. And maybe my problem is with the configuration of the nginx.

Comment: I have a working application that is served by nginx and I don't have that issue, I'm linking you my current config in case it helps: https://github.com/AlexITC/crypto-coin-alerts/blob/master/infra/nginx.conf#L17

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will try with your configuration!

Comment: just to clarify that the configuration was really taken from the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 0):

What webserver are you using?

We had the same problem with our app when publishing it with nginx

We had to change the config of the nginx to the following to allow for reloads:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Where the important part is the try_files section where he tries to match the routes and defaults to 404 if he can't find one

Comment: Hello, i was investigating and i think it's a problem with the configuration in nginx, i tried a lot of things but nothing change, so i found that the best solution is to use apache for the deployment of the angular project, because there are tons of configurations to solve this problem in apache.

Comment: Here i use this to solve my problem, but like i said i used apache instead of nginx :'c   https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2

Comment: if you look to the suggested config for nginx from the official documentation, in case that a file is not found, you return the index: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that you need to return the index page when a file is not found because different to Angular.js which used the fragment to identify the routes, Angular doesn't do that, hence, if you have '/users' and load that page directly, the browser will look for the 'users' file which won't exist, returning the index will allow the browser to load Angular and then, Angular will load the correct view from your routing module.